# Github pull request shows wrong diff

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am having two branches:
- master and
- develop.

I am trying to merge branch `develop` into `master` branch.

I have checked with Tower and Araxis merge, those two branches are identical. But when I do a pull request on Github, I am seeing that there are 381 files changed, like files are not on master at all.

Any ideas why this behavior?

Update: I am attaching screenshot of pull request.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "branches are identical"? Identical in terms of files? Or pointing at the same commit?

Comment: The files are completly the same.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am kind of same situation.

Comment: @John see my answer below

Comment: It's 2022 and I am seeing the EXACT same issue you're seeing. It's bizarre.

Answer (score 32):

Despite the misleading/broken github interface there's actually a way to get what you want. You need to drop one `.`

Instead of:

- <strike>https://github.com/account/repo/compare/ath/branchA...branchB</strike>

do

- https://github.com/account/repo/compare/ath/branchA..branchB

This compares branch heads instead of simply using the base branch to find the merge base.

github's [reponse](https://github.community/t/github-pull-requests-showing-invalid-diff-for-already-merged-branch/559) is what clued me in from @edwin-evans' response:

> `This is a result of the type of diff we use on GitHub. We use git’s three dot diff, which is the difference between the latest commit on the HEAD branch and the last common ancestor commit with the base branch.`

Comment: Based on below official doc
1. Create new branch x from base branch
2. Merge your branch into branch x
3. Check the pull request diff between base branch and x branch, the diff show work as expected
 https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#two-dot-git-diff-comparison

Comment: But why Github chooses three dots instead of two dots? When merged, two dots diff is the effective one, isn't it?

Comment: Never mind. I found [the reason](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#about-three-dot-comparison-on-github) : "Since the three-dot comparison compares with the merge base, it is focusing on 'what a pull request introduces'. When you use a two-dot comparison, the diff changes when the base branch is updated, even if you haven't made any changes to the topic branch."

Comment: Not sure what's meant by `ath` in that link. File paths in its place dont work. I used: `https://github.com/my-org/my-repo/compare/main..my-branch` which worked

Answer (score 10):

I asked this of Github Support and here is their official answer:

> We show what's called a "three-dot diff" which is the difference between the latest commit on the HEAD branch and the last common ancestor commit with the base branch. So if you forked off of a repo a while ago and things have changed in the parent repo since then, or if you opened a PR from the master branch and then the master branch has changed in the meantime, the diff wouldn't show that.

> It sounds like you'd rather see a "two-dot diff", which would show the changes between the two most recent commits on each branch. In future you can merge the base branch back into the head branch. That updates the last common ancestor and would be more likely to show you what you're expecting to see there.

So, there you have it. Merge the target branch into your PR branch and push, and this is the simplest and (imo) most proper way to solve this. I can confirm (12/20/22) that this works as I just tried it.

Comment: thanks, I thought it was a bug

Comment: This is approximately the same answer as mine 9 months later.

Comment: Or rebase your PR to the updated base branch

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled onto this problem myself and found a solution I haven't seen here or in the referenced topic on the GitHub forum. My specific situation arose because I pushed what I thought was a single commit from which I made a new PR, and then realised I hadn't pushed the commit on the top of master it was based on (i.e. when I made the PR, GitHub's view of master was one commit behind where my local one was).

I found I could reset what GitHub sees as the starting point for the PR's branch by editing the PR to change the "merge into" target from master to something else and back again. After that it showed the diffs from actual master (as it was for me locally when I made that one commit I wanted in the PR) instead of from one commit earlier.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason for which the branch comparison would be different between GitHub and your local.

If you made your branch comparison on your local repo and they were identical, a diff in the pull request must mean that either branch (maybe both?) is not up-to-date with its remote counterpart.

First do a `git fetch` to update your remote-tracking branches, then checkout each branch and make sure both are up-to-date, either by pushing or pulling, depending on your workflow.

---

**Edit** (Summary version of comments below)

When you'll have checked with

```
git branch -a -vv
```

and

```
git log --all --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline
```

the relative situation of all your branches, you *should* have different commits for `origin/master` and `origin/develop`, since GitHub shows that your `master` is behind 208 commits.

...which showed the following results :

`develop` and `origin/develop` are at commit `5db9361`.
`master` and `origin/master` are at commit `d5cc1b1`.

Could the GitHub pull request *preview* be failing? *(edit : it's **not**)*

Comment: That is exactly what my issue is. Files on both branches are the same, tested locally and remotely. `git diff remotes/origin/master remotes/origin/develop` gives me nothing.

Comment: @be-codified Sorry to ask, but are we positive you fetched before doing the diff?

Comment: Positive. Fetched, pulled and pushed, no change - for both branches.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. And it *is* odd indeed.

Comment: What are the commit hashes of `master`, `develop`, `origin/master` `origin/develop`? (I mean, which are similar / different)

Comment: You can have them all quite easily with `git log --all --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline` for example, or `git branch -a -vv` even better

Comment: *(wild shot)* Also, I know GitHub less than Bitbucket, but : on bitbucket some pull requests are not actually resolved until it's created, and the preview (like you showed here) is sometimes faulty. Maybe try creating it to check if the diff is still showing. You'll just cancel the pull request if you get the same unwanted diff.

Comment: I actually tried to create PR but I still get same diff. I have checked hashes, they are the same (5db9361 origin/develop and remotes/origin/develop, d5cc1b1 origin/master and remotes/origin/master).